# angularjs state.go doesn't reload php file

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a code which uses ui-router. It is navigating in 2 files(state). 1 is the php file which displays all the contents of an SQL db, while the other is an HTML file retrieving data from 1 row of the SQL db.

The php file is getting the contents of the db using

```
$inbox = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wps LIMIT $offset,$limit");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($inbox);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($inbox)){
      $id = $row['id'];
      $RDate = $row['RDate'];
      echo '<tr class="border_bottom">';
        echo '<td><a href="#" ng-click="GoTohtmlstate('.$id.')">'.$id.'</a></td>';
        echo '<td><a href="#" ng-click="GoTohtmlstate('.$id.')">'.$RDate.'</a></td>';
      echo '</tr>';
```

The html file is accessed by an ng-click which transfers the user in to this state and is getting the details of the SQL db row using $http.post method from a js file.

After editing the row of the SQL DB by using the HTML file, I will have to go back to the php file using $state.go. But after returning to the php file, the changes are still not reflecting.

I already tried using

```
$state.go('phpstate',{}, {reload:'phpstate'});
```

to refresh the rows displayed but it doesn't really work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code

```
$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
```

Comment: Hi the `$state.go('phpstate',{}, {reload:'phpstate'});` is used when i am in the htmlstate so that I can move back to the phpstate. Either way, it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Reload option parametr is boolean. Maybe you must try it:

```
$state.go('phpstate',{}, {reload:true});
```